# Maven depend on project - no jar but classes

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a multi-module Maven project A. There are two modules: B and C, where C depends on B.

Let's say C is a web application, so by default B.jar would be included in the WEB-INF/lib directory of C.

But instead of this, I want to compile B, and then move its compiled classes to the target directory of C.

How can I achieve this in Maven?

Thank you for your answers,

balázs

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in doing this?  This sounds like a resolution to a bigger problem.

Comment: It is. I'm trying to mavenize a 7 year old project. So far it used ant to build B and then copy some classes while compling C.

Comment: So declaring B a dependent of C doesn't work even if B is built before C?

Comment: B cannot be a dependent of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your module *B* is also a webapp module, you can create a jar file containing only the classes simply by c[onfiguring the war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached). You can then make *C* depend on that `-classes` artifact by adding `<classifier>classes</classifier>` to the pom.

Otherwise you can use the [dependency plugin to unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) the *B* artifact when *C* is packaged.

Comment: B is not a web module, it's just a project, collection of classes.

Comment: Ok, so then I'd opt for my "Otherwise" suggestion.

Comment: it pretty much looks like that your solution is the one i need :) thanks. i managed to copy the classes of B to the target dir of C but they are still not included in C.jar. Do you know how to achieve this? Execution phase maybe?

Comment: @Balázs You should make sure they are unpacked into the `target/classes` folder, and *C*'s package phase should pick them up from there.

Comment: yeah, i managed to get it right, everything works like charm. thanks again!